# The subscription of 'concierge subscription' has more than one match in cloud 'AzureCloud'

Tags: azure, sandbox, subscription, azure-cli

Using one session of an azure sandbox which lasts for 4 hours. Once one session gets expired, I've created a new sandbox to continue practicing exercises from the Azure portal.
After execuing command: `az account set --subscription "Concierge Subscription"` I am getting below error:

[image]

However, In Azure portal there is just one "Concierge Subscription". How can I close other subscription of the same name?

Comment: Specify by guid

Answer (score 8):

I think is it just the local cache of AZ cli that is not refreshed. The new subscriptions keeps adding, without removing the expired one.
Run `az account list --refresh`, this will remove the expired ones.

Comment: This was the problem for me.

Comment: we had this issue and used the `--refresh` parameter

Answer (score 2):

The `--subscription` parameter accepts either the Name or ID of a given subscription.

You can get navigate to **Subscriptions** blade on Azure Portal to get the Subscription ID of the current active Sandbox subscription, and then set that subscription to be the current active subscription using:

```
az account set -s <subscription-id>
```

Azure CLI Command reference: [az account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/account?view=azure-cli-latest)